# Install non-executable files with dh_install

Tags: packaging, debian

I have some debian package which has the following `install` file:

```
src/an_executable_python_script usr/bin
src/web/* usr/share/packagename
```

inside the `src/web` folder are some html and css files.
It looks like, that with compat level 7, everything worked fine. But with compat level 9, I get the following error message:

```
/home/user/package/debian/packagename.install: 2: 
/home/user/package/debian/packagename.install: src/web/index.html: Permission denied
```

The man page of dh_install is clear on this topic: the files must be executable.
<s>Unfortunatly, this was probably not enforced with the older debhelper, so I see that a lot of packages use this practise of installing non-executable files with dh_install.</s> edit: maybe I misunderstood the man-page. I think it means the install file itself must be executable?
But here is the thing: If i mark `index.html` executable, I'll get this error message:

```
src/web/index.html: 2: src/web/index.html: cannot open !DOCTYPE: No such file
src/web/index.html: 2: src/web/index.html: html: not found
src/web/index.html: 4: src/web/index.html: Syntax error: newline unexpected
dh_install: debian/packagename.install (executable config) returned exit code 2
```

I was not able to find out, how to install non-executable files with compat level 9, can someone give me a hint?

edit after some trial and error:
I removed the executable bit from all install files, and it works now... 
But this is contrary to the manpage?! What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901715) in dh-install. Remove the executable bit in your `.install` file.

`chmod -x debian/*.install`

Hope this answer helps someone, it took me blood sweat and tears to solve.

Comment: I only joined this community to personally thank you for this solution.

Comment: Thanks Vahid! You've made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the files mentioned in the install file are executed and not just read as instructions for the dh_install tool. Are you somewhere invoking "debian/install" by chance?

As a start, I suggest to name the install file yourpackagename.install, not just mere "install". Feel free to post your debian/rules file, too. And I would like to see an "ls -l" of the debian folder.